# React native - Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following:

```
function HomeScreen({navigation}) {

const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser?.uid;
const [user, setUser] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = firebase.firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .doc(uid)
      .onSnapshot(documentSnapshot => {
        setUser(documentSnapshot.data());
      });
    return () => subscriber();
  }, [uid]);

return (
    <Screen style={styles.screen}>
        <View>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
            <Text style={styles.nameText}>{user.username}</Text>
            <Text>hello</Text>
            <View style={{paddingBottom:20, marginRight:200, paddingTop:40}}>
                <DefaultButton 
                    title="Edit your profile" 
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate("EditProfileScreen")}
                    color='#F9CDAD' 
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    </Screen>
)
}
```

I'm trying to display the username:

```
<Text style={styles.nameText}>{user.username}</Text>
```

But im getting the following error:

> FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: undefined

When I log the `uid` defined above `const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser?.uid;`, it returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `uid` isn't set yet by the time your `userEffect` gets triggered.

To solve that, [use an auth state listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) to respond to auth state changes:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let subscriber;
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user && !subscriber) {
        subscriber = firebase.firestore()
          .collection('users')
          .doc(user.uid)
          .onSnapshot(documentSnapshot => {
            setUser(documentSnapshot.data());
        });
    });
    return () => subscriber();
  }, [uid]);
```

You'll probably need to tweak that `return` at the end, as the `subscriber` is now set asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that effectively, you are using an `undefined` value from the reference `uid` in your `useEffect()` part.

You correctly have setted it as a dependency in your dependencies array, but you are missing to check if the value is actually defined, for it to be safe to use later.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // this will run two times, first when 'uid' is initialized (as undefined) -> which will give your error
    // and then, when it gets defined with actual value.
    // --> fix: check 'uid' to be defined before using it.
    if(!uid) {
      // uid not defined yet, just return.
      return
    }
    // uid is defined here, it's safe to use.
    const subscriber = firebase.firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .doc(uid)
      .onSnapshot(documentSnapshot => {
        setUser(documentSnapshot.data());
      });
    return () => subscriber();
  }, [uid]);
```